# Is online dating permissible in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

There are many online dating and matrimonial sites solely made for Muslims so that Muslims can find their spouses on their own. Are they Halal or Haram?

Comment: Read the question there and you may find that it is more or less the same.